# Chrome not using configured proxy

Tags: linux, windows, google-chrome, proxy, squid

I am fighting and losing trying to set a proxy in Chrome that is signed into a school account. When I sign out of the account the proxy works, when I sign back in the proxy seems to stop working. Now I have gone over all of the extensions to see if anything is controlling the outbound connections, I don't see anything that stands out.

I have even set the proxy as transparent and set a nat rule on my firewall... and yet this STILL seems to bypass the proxy settings.

I am at a loss as to what to do next on how to force Chrome to use this proxy.

Squid Proxy IP: 10.0.0.2 Port: 3128

What I have tried:

*Windows: chrome.exe --proxy-server="10.0.0.2:3128"*
*Linux: chrome --proxy-server="10.0.0.2:3128"*
*NAT on Firewall*
*Windows: Internet Options: Set Proxy*
*Linux: /etc/environment global proxy settings*

None of the above have worked once Chrome is signed into the School Chrome account. Any help would be grateful! Thanks.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Good call, Thanks. https://superuser.com/questions/996927/chrome-not-using-configured-proxy